# Badge for an accepted answer on posts older than six months or more

Tags: support, badges, necromancer-badge

If we give an answer on a question which is older than six months and that answer is accepted by the OP, do we get any badge for that?

Comment: There is no badge like this. [necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) badge is something like that: `Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more` And also [revival](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/837/revival)

Comment: @hims056 Perhaps make it into an answer so we can be done with this.

Comment: @Bart Added the answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no badge like this.

But [Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) and [Revival](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/837/revival) are something like that.

**Necromancer:**

> Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more

**Revival:**

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more